Does respiration require energy?
This question in my class 10 test and my answer was "since in respiration glucose is broken down into pyruvate, thus chemical(enzymes) energy must be required." I also thought breathing is a part of respiration, this requires the lungs to be moved- thus energy required.
But my teacher says otherwise. She said I am wrong and her explanation mainly circulated around how respiration is exothermic etc...

Cellular respiration.

Sorry, couldn't grasp what the site said.

The first step in respiration is the breakdown of glucose into pyruvate. This reaction occurs in cytoplasm and is called glycolysis. Glycolysis occurs in a series of reactions. In fact, the first half of glycolysis is referred to as the 'energy requiring phase' which uses 2 ATP.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK482303/
In this article, you can get its reference.

The first phase is the "investment" phase due to its usage of two ATP molecules, and the second is the "payoff" phase. These reactions are all catalyzed by their own enzyme, with phosphofructokinase being the most essential for regulation as it controls the speed of glycolysis.

But, as others have pointed out, Respiration has no net requirement of ATP. Even, no. of ATP molecules produced are based on net production. So, it's appropriate not to consider respiration requires energy.

But glycolysis overall has no net requirement for ATP, and the way that the question was posed suggests that the overall process was what was meant. Certainly the argument of the poster were not the "phase I, phase II" of glycolysis, and the illogicality of his argument and his confusion with the role of enzymes does not suggest that he is even aware of this. You do him no service by suggesting his answer is in any way correct.

@David The poster did try to explain that phenomenon as the answer to her question. But surely there's no net change in requirement of ATP so its still as a whole is catabolic. I'll edit my answer.
